# How do I Compile Program? (TDEDecrypt Tool)

Tags: windows, compilation

I am working on a .TDE extension file and I am unsure how to decrypt it. Specifically, someone made a program but only posted it as SC. I wonder if there is any solution to run the project bcs when I do that, it does not work.

['Please select a valid startup item' Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QhYn.png)

Target Project: https://github.com/lyhyl/TDEDecrypt

I tried to import the Decryption folder to VS but I couldn't run it. Files are getting imported but when I run, I get an error which I specified before.

['Please select a valid startup item' Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QhYn.png)